# Chrome extension in developer mode (unpacked) not showing up if stored in Downloads folder (Windows)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension and sharing it with colleagues to test/use. It turns out that if I share my extension as a zipped file and send it to them for testing, those using Windows OS and who uncompress the file there where they got it (Downloads folder) can't see it listed in the file explorer dialog after clicking the "Load unpacked extension..." under chrome//extensions. If they move the extracted folder elsewhere (i.e. Desktop) they can see it without problem.

Is this normal? I haven't been found any reference to such problem anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Simply drag'n'drop the extension directory onto chrome://extensions page.

Comment: And in case you are manually zipping up your directory to create a .zip, try using the "Pack Extension" button.